# How to write else if as logical statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic

I want to write an if-else statement as a logical statement. I know that:

```
if (statement1){
   b=c
}
else{
   b=d
}
```

can be written as:

```
b=(statement1 && c)||(!statement1 && d)
```

But how do I write the following if-else statements as logical?:

```
if (statement1){
   b=c
}
else if (statement2){
   b=d
}
else{
   b=e
}
```

I have thought of something like:

```
b=(statement1 && c)||(statement2 && d)||((!statement1&&!statement2) && e)
```

I'm sorry if there is already a post about this. I have tried, but couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

Comment: You could write: `b = (statement1 ? c : (statement2 ? d : e));`. `?` is the ternary operator. It is used in an expression of the form `predicate ? value_if_predicate_holds_true : value_if_predicate_holds_false`.

Comment: What are the types of `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`?

Comment: Thank you @rturrado, I'm not sure I know what ? and : stands for though. Can ? be interrupted as &&?

Comment: No, it can't be. What does your C++ textbook say about these operators? Is there anything in your textbook's explanation that's unclear?

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko b is a bit that represents false=0 or true=1. And c is therefore 0, d is 1 and e can be 0 or 1.

Comment: @AlphaList `?` should be interpreted as `if`, and `:` as `else`. `b = (statement1 ? c : d);` should be interpreted as `if (statement1) { b = c; } else { b = d; }`.

Comment: i suppose all variables are `bool`, becaues otherwise already your first example is not necessarily correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all logical statement building, it'll be easiest to create a truth table here. You'll end up with:

```
+--+--+--------+
|s2|s1| result |
+--+--+--------+
| 0| 0|   e    |
+--+--+--------+
| 0| 1|   c    |
+--+--+--------+
| 1| 0|   d    |
+--+--+--------+
| 1| 1|   c    |
+--+--+--------+
```

So un-simplified, that'll be

```
(!s1 & !s2 & e) || (!s2 & s1 & c) || (s2 & !s1 & d) || (s1 & s2 & c)
```

This can be simplified by combining the two `c` results and removing the `s2`:

```
(!s1 & !s2 & e) || (s2 & !s1 & d) || (s1 & c)
```

(note that this will be faster in C++ and match the `if` statements closer with `s1 & c` as the first term. This will especially make a difference if evaluating any of these values will cause outside effects)

---

Note that what you built,

```
(statement1 && c)||(statement2 && d)||((!statement1&&!statement2) && e)
```

will function incorrectly if `statement1` is true, `c` is false, and both `statement2` and `d` are true (you'll get a result of true when you should have false).

Comment: Rewriting with the `(s1 & c)` clause in front would yield some improvement when both `s1` and `s2` are non-trivial computations, because it would let you skip computing of `s2` when `s1` and `c` are both `true`

Comment: @Sergey you're right from a C++ perspective with short-circuiting. I was treating this as a boolean algebra problem, so those terms are simply in the order I read them off the table. I'll edit in a note of that tho. Good catch!